# Is the Xcode 6 UIWebView not compatible with iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift, ios8

I am very new to iOS programing and am right now using Swift to do coding with XCode.

I want to use UIWebView on my app. I created a webview and used the following code to run it.

```
 var url = NSURL(string:"http://some-website.special.page.com/");
 var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url);
 webView.loadRequest(req);
```

This works perfectly on a ioS8 simulator and phone but when i try to execute/deploy the same on a simulator/iPhone with 7.1 the app crash!

All i get is the following error on XCode.

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
0x8fe460b4:  int3   
0x8fe460b5:  nop
```

Going through stack overflow older post i stumbled upon this post [Which is the cause for dyld`dyld_fatal_error, a incompatible api on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325529/which-is-the-cause-for-dylddyld-fatal-error-a-incompatible-api-on-ios)
which also talks about this error. But in my case i have not used any additional framework. I think it should be compatability issue with the webkit. Not sure if i am thinking on the right direction. Whats the work around on this as i want my app to be backward compatible as well as use ios8 features? Appreciate any help.

Comment: iOS 8 introduced WKWebView. Can you confirm whether you're using UIWebView or WKWebView?

Comment: Using UIWebView.  @IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problem happens on OS X too.

If I use 10.9 SDK but have the code compiled using Xcode 6 beta 2 on Yosemite, the binary runs w/o problem on Yosemite, but it crashed on 10.9; if the exact same code was compiled in Xcode 6 beta 2 on a 10.9.3 machine, it runs without problem on 10.9 but got random crashes on Yosemite.

I guess there's either a bug regarding the system or SDK in Xcode 6 beta, but can't be sure.

(Sorry I was mean to use the comment, but my reputation wasn't > 50.)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping atleast someone can check that they are also getting the same issue or am i doing something wrong as am relatively new to the whole xcode programming.

Comment: I will mark this as solved. This issue was a Beta 2 xcode issue and has been fixed in Beta 3. Question can be closed. Thanks.

Comment: Nope. Seems to still be a problem for me