# Getting dyld_fatal_error after updating to Xcode 6 beta 4 using swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I just recently downloaded Xcode 6 beta 4, and my swift project compiles with no errors but before it gets to my code I get a dyld_fatal_error just above start in the call stack.

[image: call stack]

and a breakpoint in some assembly code with a nop instruction

[image: breakpoint]

The console error I get is

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __TFSsa6C_ARGVGVSs13UnsafePointerGS_VSs4Int8__
  Referenced from: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sudoku-dhrdonaeqzsgcvewndimxbbsltnc/Build/Products/Debug/Sudoku.app/Contents/MacOS/Sudoku
  Expected in: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sudoku-dhrdonaeqzsgcvewndimxbbsltnc/Build/Products/Debug/Sudoku.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: __TFSsa6C_ARGVGVSs13UnsafePointerGS_VSs4Int8__
  Referenced from: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sudoku-dhrdonaeqzsgcvewndimxbbsltnc/Build/Products/Debug/Sudoku.app/Contents/MacOS/Sudoku
  Expected in: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sudoku-dhrdonaeqzsgcvewndimxbbsltnc/Build/Products/Debug/Sudoku.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib
```

Just so you know the project still compiles, and runs fine with Xcode 6 beta 3.

Comment: Have you tried clean + build?

Comment: Actually no let me try that

Comment: Wow I feel so dumb thanks @jtbandes post that as an answer, and I will accept it. :)

Comment: I am also experiencing this problem! Trying the restarting solution proposed below....

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Most extremely weird problems like this can be solved with a Clean & Build (or perhaps relaunch Xcode). You might also consider deleting the relevant folders from ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData.

Comment: Yep! Clean + Build is the solution!

Comment: I had both Xcode 6 and 6.1 on my system, and turns out 6.0 was trying to use 6.1's derived data folder...so yes, nuking the folder & clean/build worked! Thanks!

Comment: For anyone facing a similar issue I'd like to add that this issue can be related to many reasons. In the below answers there are described many different things you can do to solve this issue, so if the first solution doesn't work it's worth checking below. These are: 1. Clean, 2. Manually deleting folders, 3. Adding framework to Embedded Binary, 4. Adding framework to Copy phase, 5. Changing the Deployment target, 6. Cleaning Library cache, 7. Issues with certificates, etc.

Answer (score 25):

For sure this error is very unhelpful:

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
->  0x1200ad088 <+0>: brk    #0x3
```

This of course occurs only on device, *not the simulator*. Another good reason to always test on a device.

Anyway, having had the same issue, a clean didn't work for me. Deleting DerivedData didn't help either. Also tried synchronising the Deployment Target versions. That didn't seem make any difference but I did it anyway.

Solution was to add any dynamic frameworks to Embedded Binaries setting under Target -> General:

[image: setting an embedded binary]

Now I know that has been mentioned in other answers. However, if I can supplement by saying that any *dependent* dynamic frameworks must also be included.

So for example if you have a dynamic framework *A* that depends upon dynamic framework *B*, then it's necessary to have *A* and *B* added to Embedded Binaries.

Note that if the dynamic framework *A* depends upon any static library or framework, you will almost certainly be forced to create *A* as an umbrella framework that includes the dependant binaries.

Other considerations that may or may not be important. However did personally for me result in success were;

- paths of each dynamic library in the Inspector were set to "Relative
     to Group". In the screen grab above the path of the embedded binary
     appears correct terminating with `"build/Debug-iphoneos"`.
- dynamic frameworks are in embedded binaries section. Static libs and
         static libs wrapped up as frameworks are in Linked Frameworks
         and Libraries. *Nothing appears in both sections.*

In setting this up XCode behaved strangely. The following proved successful:

1. Add the dynamic framework to the embedded binaries.
2. Find the new   framework in XCode groups on the left and update the path to be
   *"Relative to Group"* as described previously.
3. Delete the dynamic framework from embedded binaries.
4. Add the dynamic framework to the embedded binaries again. The path should now appear correctly.
5. Delete all references to the dynamic framework from the Linked Frameworks
   and Libraries section.

Comment: Excellent answer. Do you have any idea why sometimes a dynamic framework (i.e., a cocoa touch framework) appears in the project navigator as a yellow suitcase and other times as a white lego box with one edge facing out? I wonder if sometimes this reflects different ways Xcode might import a framework, but I have no idea what the difference could be or if it is significant for using the framework.

Comment: I also found going outside turning round three times and spitting to be helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped. I am curious, are these dylib imports?

Answer (score 17):

I have just had this problem trying to link a custom iOS framework to my project, so for anyone out there who has this problem, it's to do with the copy files build phase.

I think that this error results when a file cannot be found. So create a copy files build phase in the appropriate target in your project. Then add the file (in my case the custom framework) to this phase (if it's a framework make sure to select the 'Frameworks' destination).

Comment: Great tip. This is exactly what I was looking for. Clearly other people are looking for something else, but this is neccessary for frameworks.

Comment: Thank you. You saved me endless hours of searching. This is still a thing in xcode 7 beta.

Answer (score 9):

*Cleaning, restarting, deleting etc didn't work for me.*

I have a project *containing* another project. When I ran the project on iOS 7 and the *contained* project was accessed in code, the app stopped at the line below:

[image]

After many days, I saw that the deployment target for the *container* project was **7.0** *(as can be seen below)*.

[image]

The *contained* project on the other hand, had a deployment target of **8.1** *(as can be seen below)*.
[image]

Changing the deployment target of the *contained* project to 7.0 solved my problem!

*The project was working fine on iOS 8 devices.*

Comment: Spot on for my issue.  I don't think I changed my Deployment Target, so I'm not sure if that happened during some automatic settings updates or what.  Frustrating.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue recently and the problem for me was that I had added a library from the same project which wasn't listed in 'Embedded Binaries' from the 'General' section.

NOTE: If you add it in Embedded Binaries it will also add to the Linked Libraries section, possibly adding the same one twice.

Comment: Thanks: for the device, "Embedded Binaries" is necessary, while on the simulator "linked frameworks" is enough. What? Anyway, this was helpful to me, thanks!

Comment: @DanRosenstark I know, it's silly. Had the exact same problem with sample code I was trying to share that worked on the simulator but no one could get working on the device

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the real answer is "stop all this madness and use Cocoapods..." For some reason I forgot about them this time around -- and gave up on them long ago when things were frustrating -- but I'm going to head back in. LOTS of documentation around Cocoapods and lots of love from people around the World. You can **even** do this: [private repos](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html)

Comment: @DanRosenstark yes, using cocoapods is great and will probably mitigate the issue. I'd recommend them (swift is supposed to have its own module manager coming too, actually). Ironically though, I posted my original answer after the example project of my cocoapod had this issue o.O

Comment: Sorry, you're saying that you had this issue after following the instructions for a Cocoapods HelloWorld? (another manager... ugh?! Great!?)

Comment: @DanRosenstark No, if you use cocoapods you should be fine.

Comment: I just did a pretty massive Cocoapods HelloWorld, with full writeup

https://workflowy.com/s/ADHHpFWiPJ#/bc6a66ad3cf5

Answer (score 5):

Clean and build won't work. You'll need to delete he cache in ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode* directories. Delete these and rebuild.

Do this every time you upgrade the beta.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue and tried all the solution given above without any luck.

then what I have done to resolve that I really don’t have much I idea about. So there is Certificated called “**apple worldwide developer relations certificate authority**” in System group in keychain Access and due to some profile and certificate issue I randomly mark this certificate “**Always trusted**” from “**Use System Defaults**”. So this is causing this “`dyld_fatal_error`” crash to me. when I revert it back to “**Use System Defaults**” crash got resolved.
[image]
So guys if you are tried all the possible option to resolve this crash and didn’t succeed yet, try this also. It helped me, may help you as well.

Found [this](https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/) about this certificate.

Comment: My problem was not in Apple Worldwide certificate, but in specific developer certificate. So try to set to *"Use System Defaults"* for all developer profiles.

Comment: Thanks Suryakant Sharma. This was the same mistake I did. Had spent hours looking for this issue, until I stumbled onto your answer. Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: This worked but I also had to do a deep clean then close and re-open Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

This problem still occurs in Xcode 7, and it can happen for a variety of reasons (it seems). In my case, the iOS app with an included framework:

1. ran on the simulator fine
2. gave the error you described on the device

The answer was to NOT use linked libraries but rather **Embedded Binaries under General.**

Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34052368/8047

Answer (score 1):

Adding the non-system Framework to "Embedded Binaries" inside the general tab of the main project worked for me.

As stated by bitwit, this will also add your framework to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", so watch out for those duplicates.

Tested with Xcode 7.3.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 8.

Clean and build didn't work. I deleted the cache, deleted Derived data. After that, my pods configuration was broken, so i needed to install pods again. Pods Target configuration was set to a very old Valid architectures. setting to armv7 and armv7s, was ok to compile and no problems

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this if your scheme has "Guard Edges" enabled in diagnostics when running on an actual device.  "Guard Edges" only works in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I was using cocoapods and had this problem as well when I updated to deploy target iOS 8 and added `use_frameworks!` to my `Podfile`. I was able to fix it by adding the following line to my `Podfile`:

`link_with 'TargetName1', 'TargetName2', etc.`

Might work with `ProjectName` as well