# Xcode won't add "Embedded binary" after deleting "DerivedData"

Tags: ios, iphone, frameworks, xcode6, apple-watch

**Alternative titles to aid search:**

- Adding Embedded Binaries fails in Xcode
- Xcode won't link framework from separate project
- App crashes on device because of missing framework, works in simulator

## Overview

After deleting the "DerivedData" folder (or performing a "Product > Clean") in [xcode6](/questions/tagged/xcode6), I cannot add CocoaTouch frameworks from another project to the "Embedded Binary" section (under General tab).

Or, Xcode hits a linker error because it cannot find a framework that if previously could.

## Other symptoms

Clicking on the + under "Embedded Binaries" shows the Framework selector but selecting a framework in different project in the workspace does nothing.

Comment: Take a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878274/getting-dyld-fatal-error-after-updating-to-xcode-6-beta-4-using-swift/35654969#35654969

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This it the only way i have discovered to restore the embedded binaries, please leave comments if you find some steps are not required.

**Prerequisites:** Read [Daniel Tull's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27782710/89035).

1. Remove all framework projects from the workspace
2. Perform a **"clean build"** and/or remove the "DerivedData"
3. Add project back into the workspace
4. Build the project *(possibly optional)*
5. In the General tab of the app target click the + under **"Linked Frameworks and Libraries"**, select the framework.
6. Build and run in the Simulator (there should be no issues building or running)
7. Build and run for device (this might cause a crash due to the framework not being correctly linked, ignore this crash)
8. Click the + under **"Embedded Binaries"**, select the framework. This should add it to the project (possible duplicate under "Linked Frameworks and Libraries")
9. Repeat for all required frameworks
10. Once building and running (on device) is confirmed you can remove any duplicate (and/or red) frameworks in the Project Navigator or target General tab

Answer (score 45):

When you add the framework to the **Embedded Binaries**, there will be a reference added to your project for it. If you select that reference after your steps above, you will probably find that it has an *Absolute Path* reference to the framework rather than a relative one, which we'd like. Change the location to *Relative to Build Products* and the reference should always be discoverable if do a "hard" clean or use another computer etc.

I have [made a video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3q91mwywyuaafx6/Frameworks.mov) which describes how best to add a built framework from one project to an app target in another sibling project.

Comment: Thank you very much - not sure I'd ever have worked this out!

Comment: The Location dropdown is grayed out for me and won't let me change to Relative. Hmm.

Comment: @Tres, hope you've solved your issue by now, but here's an advice for others with same issue. You must make sure to select the right file. You should choose your framework in the Project navigator in your app project (not framework project). Look at my answer below, I've added an image to better explain.

Comment: WOW thank you so much!!! I burned so many days and brain cells on this. Why would Xcode or any IDE ever default to an absolute path setting?!?!!@#$@^!$#^

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Daniel's answer, if your Location dropdown is greyed out you may have selected the wrong file. Make sure to select the framework that's in your app project (not framework project).

[image]