# Xcode: relative path on embedded binaries

Tags: shared-libraries, swift2, xcode7

I need to include a framework on

```
General -> Embedded Libraries
```

to make my application works.
There are two ways (known by me) to do this: drag and drop or clicking button "+" and choosing the framework. In both cases, Xcode put an absolute path.

There is a way to put a relative path?

I'm thinking to do from terminal with nano editing:

```
ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27782710/5276890) should work.
I've also looked into hacking the pbxproj file. 
It seems doable, if somewhat cryptic.
if the above answer doesn't work for you, leave a comment and I'll look into it.
And of course, don't forget to reward [Daniel Tull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155863/daniel-tull).