# getting error "dyld_sim`dyld_fatal_error" after app starts

Tags: ios, runtime-error, fatal-error

```
dyld_sim`dyld_fatal_error:

    0x103e63000 <+0>: int3   
->  0x103e63001 <+1>: nop
```

- My app is compile & build successfully but it ends with above error.
- There're no other messages (error logs).
- I set breakpoints in AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunghingWithOptions` method and in `main.m` also. But it never stops there.
- My app's first view is always visible and error is coming only after it.

I couldn't find anything regarding this error – how can I solve it? Any specific suggestions.

I also tried this,

- change frameworks type from Required to Optional.

But nothing works !!

And yes, I'm using CocoaPods.

**Update**:

My question isn't matched with any other questions, as both having contradict in titles.

Error which I'm getting - dyld_sim`dyld_fatal_error

Error in duplicate (suggestion) question - dyld`dyld_fatal_error:

**Update 2**:
[image]

**Update 3**:

Crash log

```
    dyld_sim`dyldbootstrap::rebaseDyld:
    0x10f95c002 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x10f95c003 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10f95c006 <+4>:   pushq  %r15
    0x10f95c008 <+6>:   pushq  %r14
    0x10f95c00a <+8>:   pushq  %r13
    0x10f95c00c <+10>:  pushq  %r12
    0x10f95c00e <+12>:  pushq  %rbx
    0x10f95c00f <+13>:  subq   $0x18, %rsp
    0x10f95c013 <+17>:  movq   %rsi, %rbx
    0x10f95c016 <+20>:  movq   %rdi, %r14
    0x10f95c019 <+23>:  movl   0x10(%r14), %r13d
    0x10f95c01d <+27>:  addq   $0x20, %r14
    0x10f95c021 <+31>:  xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x10f95c023 <+33>:  movq   %rax, -0x30(%rbp)
    0x10f95c027 <+37>:  xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x10f95c029 <+39>:  movq   %rax, -0x38(%rbp)
    0x10f95c02d <+43>:  xorl   %r12d, %r12d
    0x10f95c030 <+46>:  xorl   %r15d, %r15d
->  0x10f95c033 <+49>:  movl   (%r14), %eax
    0x10f95c036 <+52>:  cmpl   $0xb, %eax
    0x10f95c039 <+55>:  jne    0x10f95c043               ; <+65>
    0x10f95c03b <+57>:  movq   %r14, %r12
    0x10f95c03e <+60>:  jmp    0x10f95c0cc               ; <+202>
    0x10f95c043 <+65>:  cmpl   $0x19, %eax
    0x10f95c046 <+68>:  jne    0x10f95c0cc               ; <+202>
    0x10f95c04c <+74>:  leaq   0x8(%r14), %rdi
    0x10f95c050 <+78>:  leaq   0x192c0(%rip), %rsi       ; "__LINKEDIT"
    0x10f95c057 <+85>:  callq  0x10f9751a2               ; strcmp
    0x10f95c05c <+90>:  testl  %eax, %eax
    0x10f95c05e <+92>:  movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rax
    0x10f95c062 <+96>:  cmoveq %r14, %rax
    0x10f95c066 <+100>: movq   %rax, -0x30(%rbp)
    0x10f95c06a <+104>: leaq   0x48(%r14), %rax
    0x10f95c06e <+108>: movl   0x40(%r14), %ecx
    0x10f95c072 <+112>: leaq   (%rcx,%rcx,4), %rcx
    0x10f95c076 <+116>: shlq   $0x4, %rcx
    0x10f95c07a <+120>: leaq   0x48(%r14,%rcx), %rcx
    0x10f95c07f <+125>: jmp    0x10f95c085               ; <+131>
    0x10f95c081 <+127>: addq   $0x50, %rax
    0x10f95c085 <+131>: cmpq   %rcx, %rax
    0x10f95c088 <+134>: jae    0x10f95c0b3               ; <+177>
    0x10f95c08a <+136>: movzbl 0x40(%rax), %edx
    0x10f95c08e <+140>: cmpl   $0x6, %edx
    0x10f95c091 <+143>: jne    0x10f95c081               ; <+127>
    0x10f95c093 <+145>: movq   0x28(%rax), %rdx
    0x10f95c097 <+149>: shrq   $0x3, %rdx
    0x10f95c09b <+153>: testl  %edx, %edx
    0x10f95c09d <+155>: je     0x10f95c081               ; <+127>
    0x10f95c09f <+157>: movq   0x20(%rax), %rsi
    0x10f95c0a3 <+161>: addq   %rbx, %rsi
    0x10f95c0a6 <+164>: addq   %rbx, (%rsi)
    0x10f95c0a9 <+167>: addq   $0x8, %rsi
    0x10f95c0ad <+171>: decl   %edx
    0x10f95c0af <+173>: jne    0x10f95c0a6               ; <+164>
    0x10f95c0b1 <+175>: jmp    0x10f95c081               ; <+127>
    0x10f95c0b3 <+177>: cmpq   $0x0, -0x38(%rbp)
    0x10f95c0b8 <+182>: jne    0x10f95c0cc               ; <+202>
    0x10f95c0ba <+184>: testb  $0x2, 0x3c(%r14)
    0x10f95c0bf <+189>: movl   $0x0, %eax
    0x10f95c0c4 <+194>: cmovneq %r14, %rax
    0x10f95c0c8 <+198>: movq   %rax, -0x38(%rbp)
    0x10f95c0cc <+202>: movl   0x4(%r14), %eax
    0x10f95c0d0 <+206>: addq   %rax, %r14
    0x10f95c0d3 <+209>: incl   %r15d
    0x10f95c0d6 <+212>: cmpl   %r13d, %r15d
    0x10f95c0d9 <+215>: jne    0x10f95c033               ; <+49>
    0x10f95c0df <+221>: movl   0x48(%r12), %esi
    0x10f95c0e4 <+226>: movl   0x4c(%r12), %edx
    0x10f95c0e9 <+231>: testq  %rdx, %rdx
    0x10f95c0ec <+234>: je     0x10f95c13d               ; <+315>
    0x10f95c0ee <+236>: movq   -0x38(%rbp), %rax
    0x10f95c0f2 <+240>: movq   0x18(%rax), %rax
    0x10f95c0f6 <+244>: addq   %rbx, %rax
    0x10f95c0f9 <+247>: movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rcx
    0x10f95c0fd <+251>: movq   %rcx, %rdi
    0x10f95c100 <+254>: movq   0x18(%rdi), %rcx
    0x10f95c104 <+258>: addq   %rbx, %rcx
    0x10f95c107 <+261>: addq   %rsi, %rcx
    0x10f95c10a <+264>: subq   0x28(%rdi), %rcx
    0x10f95c10e <+268>: leaq   (%rcx,%rdx,8), %rdx
    0x10f95c112 <+272>: movl   0x4(%rcx), %esi
    0x10f95c115 <+275>: movl   %esi, %edi
    0x10f95c117 <+277>: andl   $0x6000000, %edi
    0x10f95c11d <+283>: cmpl   $0x6000000, %edi
    0x10f95c123 <+289>: jne    0x10f95c14c               ; <+330>
    0x10f95c125 <+291>: cmpl   $0x10000000, %esi
    0x10f95c12b <+297>: jae    0x10f95c15f               ; <+349>
    0x10f95c12d <+299>: movslq (%rcx), %rsi
    0x10f95c130 <+302>: addq   %rbx, (%rax,%rsi)
    0x10f95c134 <+306>: addq   $0x8, %rcx
    0x10f95c138 <+310>: cmpq   %rdx, %rcx
    0x10f95c13b <+313>: jb     0x10f95c112               ; <+272>
    0x10f95c13d <+315>: addq   $0x18, %rsp
    0x10f95c141 <+319>: popq   %rbx
    0x10f95c142 <+320>: popq   %r12
    0x10f95c144 <+322>: popq   %r13
    0x10f95c146 <+324>: popq   %r14
    0x10f95c148 <+326>: popq   %r15
    0x10f95c14a <+328>: popq   %rbp
    0x10f95c14b <+329>: retq   
    0x10f95c14c <+330>: movl   $0x8, %edi
    0x10f95c151 <+335>: callq  0x10f9710ea               ; __cxa_allocate_exception
    0x10f95c156 <+340>: leaq   0x191c5(%rip), %rcx       ; "relocation in dyld has wrong size"
    0x10f95c15d <+347>: jmp    0x10f95c170               ; <+366>
    0x10f95c15f <+349>: movl   $0x8, %edi
    0x10f95c164 <+354>: callq  0x10f9710ea               ; __cxa_allocate_exception
    0x10f95c169 <+359>: leaq   0x191d4(%rip), %rcx       ; "relocation in dyld has wrong type"
    0x10f95c170 <+366>: movq   %rcx, (%rax)
    0x10f95c173 <+369>: leaq   0x24c56(%rip), %rcx       ; typeinfo for char const*
    0x10f95c17a <+376>: xorl   %edx, %edx
    0x10f95c17c <+378>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10f95c17f <+381>: movq   %rcx, %rsi
    0x10f95c182 <+384>: callq  0x10f971354               ; __cxa_throw
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is the cause for dyld\`dyld\_fatal\_error, a incompatible api on iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325529/which-is-the-cause-for-dylddyld-fatal-error-a-incompatible-api-on-ios)

Comment: So it looks like the dynamic linker cannot find a `.dylib` or `.framework`.  Do you know which one?

Comment: I'd like to know what library is failing to load.  There will be an error message starting `dyld: Library not loaded: ...`.  Please update your question with it.

Comment: Without any clue as to why the dynamic linker is so upset, there isn't much that can be done to help you.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue after deleting a bunch of things to try and fix another issue. I was able to fix it by reverting the following:
In Project>Build Settings>Runpath Search Paths, add the following (using the + icon, values are comma separated):

```
$(inherited), @executable_path/Frameworks, @loader_path/Frameworks
```

Unfortunately, SO text editor made me write it in a code block.

Comment: Adding this to runpath search paths and then re-running the code made the "library not loaded" error show in the console, which then let me debug further why the particular library wasn't being found (in my case it was a custom library). Before adding this, I was not getting any error messages in the console, just the fatal error